# Change of basis matrix $C$ by partitioned matrix $[M_{B'}|M_B] \sim [I|C]$

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Let $M_B$ and $M_{B'}$ be the matrices with the vectors in the bases $B$ and $B'$, respectively, as column vectors.

Let $\mathbf v$ be a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ with coordinate vectors $\mathbf v_B$ and $\mathbf v_{B'}$ relative to bases $B$ and $B'$, respectively. $\mathbf v$ can then be written in the form $M_B \mathbf v_B$ or $M_{B'} \mathbf v_{B'}$. This yields $\mathbf v_{B'} = M^{-1}_{B'}M_B \mathbf v_B = C_{B,B'} \mathbf v_B\ .$

The text I'm reading (Fraleigh Bouregard,3rd) introduces a direct method to compute this $C_{B,B'}$, if $M_B$ and $M_{B'}$ are given. Namely, by the row reduction $$[M_{B'}|M_B] \sim [I|C_{B,B'}] \ .$$

It explains this by

> We can regard this reduction as solving $n$ linear systems, one for each column vector of $M_B$ and all having the same coefficient matrix $M_{B'}$. From this perspective, the matrix $M_{B'}$ times the $j$th column vector of $C_{B,B'}$ (that is, the $j$th "solution vector") must yield the $j$th column vector of $M_B$. This shows that $M_{B'}C_{B,B'}=M_B$. Consequently, we must have $C_{B,B'}=M^{-1}_{B'}M_B$.

Now, the explanation above completely eludes me.

How is this reduction $[M_{B'}|M_B] \sim [I|C_{B,B'}]$ regarded as solving $n$ linear systems, one for each column vector of $M_B$ (all having the same coefficient matrix $M_{B'}$)?
I know how you would regard it as solving $n$ linear systems with only one column vector as the augmented matrix, but not with multiple column vectors as it the case here.

How does the matrix $M_{B'}$ times the $j$th column vector of $C_{B,B'}$ yield the $j$th column vector of $M_B$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the example of an augmented matrix

$$
[B|\mathbf a]=
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
    \mid & \mid & \dots & \mid & \mid \\
    \mathbf b_1 & \mathbf b_2 & \dots & \mathbf b_n & \mathbf a \\
    \mid & \mid & \dots & \mid & \mid
  \end{array}\right]
$$

First thing to note is the invariance of solution sets under row equivalence.

Hence, the row reduced matrix $[I|\mathbf a']$ has the same solution set as $ [B|\mathbf a]$. This means the linear systems $B\mathbf x = \mathbf a$ and $I\mathbf x = \mathbf a'$ have the same solutions. Thus, the entries of $\mathbf a'$ give the linear combination of basis vectors in $B$ that add up to $\mathbf a$.

Now, back to the question.

*How is this reduction $[M_{B'}|M_B] \sim [I|C_{B,B'}]$ regarded as solving $n$ linear systems, one for each column vector of $M_B$ (all having the same coefficient matrix $M_{B'}$)?*

Well, for each column in the (row reduced) augmented part of the matrix, its column represents the linear combination of basis vectors $B$ that add up to the same column in the pre row reduced matrix.

So, if we put
$$
[B|A]=
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
    \mid & \mid & \dots & \mid & \mid & \mid & \dots &\mid \\
    \mathbf b_1 & \mathbf b_2 & \dots & \mathbf b_n & \mathbf a_1 & \mathbf a_2 & \dots & \mathbf a_n\\
    \mid & \mid & \dots & \mid & \mid & \mid & \dots &\mid 
  \end{array}\right] \sim [I|A']\ ,
$$

the column $\mathbf a'_j$ of $A'$ has as components the linear combination of basis vectors $B$ that add up to $\mathbf a_j$.

Now, for the last part of the question.

*How does the matrix $M_{B'}$ times the $j$th column vector of $C_{B,B'}$ yield the $j$th column vector of $M_B$?*

This is clear from the previous discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally true that the column vectors of a basis change matrix $C_{B,B'}$
are $(b_1)_{B'}, (b_2)_{B'}, \dots ,(b_n)_{B'}$ where $B = (b_1,b_2, \dots, b_n)$.

So the $j$'th column of $C_{B,B'}$ is $(b_j)_{B'}$.

It is also a fact that the result of multiplying $M_{B'} ($which is a by context a short notation for $M_{B',S}$ where $S$ is the standard basis) by a coordinates vector $v_{B'}$ yields $v$ (namely $M_{B'}v_{B'} = v$)

So we have $M_{B'}(b_j)_{B'} = b_j$ which is the $j$'th column of $M_B$

Hope this helps